# Passing variables between classes in different files in python

Tags: python, class, variables, parameter-passing

I think the title is already kind of explicatory. Say I have a class:

```
# Class in file 1
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
         x = 10
```

is it possible to pass the variable "x" into another class stored in another file? Say for example:

```
# Class in file 2
class Foo(object):
    def print_variable(x):
         print(x)
```

Comment: Nope, the first ``x`` is limited to the local scope of the function ``__init__`` and cannot be used anywhere else. This sounds like an XY problem or very bad design in the first place.

Comment: The fact they are in different files is not important.  Either these are both imported from a third, main file, or one imports from the other.  They become two different classes with two different namespaces   Also, as @MikeScotty points out, the way your file 1 `Foo.__init__`  is defined, x is a temporary local variable and disappears as soon as your object is initialized.  Are you perhaps trying to combine classes, as in inheritance?

Comment: @RufusVS No but I could try that. if I use inheritance then all the parameters of the "super" class will be available to the "child" class right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to inherit from the first class. For example:

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, age):
        self.age = age
  
    def print_age(self):
        print(self.age)

class Cat(Dog):
    def __init__(self):
        Dog.__init__(self, age) 

x = Cat(10)
x.print_age()
```

Obviously this may not be a direct answer but you can do a lot more with inheritance.

Comment: But you just need to import the other class for example: "from file_name import Dog"